# Image Magick image moving to anthoer folder

Tags: image, image-processing, imagemagick

Is there any command-line in image magick to move images to another folder, which contains morethan 400 width or morethan 600 height.

I am using windows 7

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should be able to adapt my answer here easily enough... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26560393/image-magick-change-image-width-and-height/26560589#26560589

Answer (score 0):

Here is an ImageMagick command that will output `1` if the image is wider than 400 pixels or taller than 600 pixels, else it will output `0`. You should be able to use some Windows `FOR /F` command to move the file accordingly:

```
convert image.png -format "%[fx:(w>400)||(h>600)?1:0]" info:
```